# Can I (safely) give a variable the same like method name?

Tags: java, coding-style

In my java code I did something like that:

```
int sleep = 0;
sleep(sleep);
sleep++;
```

It was pointed out by my bos that it is not good. That it won't work in php correctly.

Is there any issue / danger using above code in java?

Comment: sorry but horrible naming imho..

Comment: Should be fine in Java, but I wouldn't recommend it as it can be a little confusing to read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no danger, since methods will never be referred to without the parentheses for arguments, so the names will never clash.

However it's generally clearer and more intuitive if method names are verbs and variable names are nouns, for example:

```
int sleepMillis = 0;
sleep(sleepMillis);
sleepMillis++;
```

Comment: @Radek often you can rename things that are ambiguous e.g. `sleep` (the variable) is the sleeping period and hence could be named `period`.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a syntax reason why you can't do it, but as a general development principle, it's generally clearer if you don't use the same names, for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried that before but I assume it would work correctly since Java should be able to distinguish the different between a variable and a method. It should work but code like that is confusing. Don't make give variables names that match a method you'll be using.

Answer (score 1):

It's confusing, to say the least. Not really a problem, since the compiler will point to you if you try to use the method where a variable is expected (or vice versa), thanks to the fact that Java is statically typed.

The same code would be much more problematic in a dynamically typed language with first-order functions, where in fact a variable can point to a function or a value with no way to distinguish between them until runtime.